# Проблема при вызове функции

Tags: python, django

Есть [views.py](http://views.py):

```
def view(request):
    ...
    InfoMessage.createinfo('self',request.user, 3)
    ...
```

И модель

```
class InfoMessage(models.Model):
    to_view=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    choice=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=INFO_MESSAGE_CHOICES)
    user=models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)

def createinfo(self, user, choice):
    obj=super(InfoMessage, self).objects.create(user=user, choice=choice)
    obj.save()
```

В итоге получаю

> unbound method createinfo() must be
> called with InfoMessage instance as
> first argument (got str instance
> instead)

Как это исправить?

Comment: Да, я во вьюшке одной строкой и сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `'self'`.

Comment: В каком месте? А то их там много.

Comment: во вьюшке, где вызываешь InfoMessage.createinfo('self',request.user, 3)

Comment: без него пробовал, не помогает

Comment: выдает "unbound method createinfo() must be called with InfoMessage instance as first argument (got CustomUser instance instead)"

Comment: Ну получается, инстанса еще нет, нужно сначала создать, а потом вызывать метод использующий self.

А вообще выглядит все несколько странно. Какова цель? Просто сделать запись, зачем тогда этот метод? почему не сделать:

    msg = InfoMessage.objects.create(choice='3', user=request.user)
    msg.save()

?

Comment: Хотел сделать через отдельный метод модели, как бы лаконичнее во вьюшке. Вот тоже пришел к выводу, что делать во вьюхе менее проблемно

Comment: прошу прощения, я немного сам запутался, если использовать objects.create() , то потом вызывать .save() не нужно. Т.е. это как раз то, что ты хотел, одной строкой сделать запись в базу, я правильно понял?